# R Conditional Formatting in Loops

Tags: r, for-loop, random, conditional-statements

I'm trying to iterate through a df with a number of addresses in different neighborhoods, and for each neighborhood I would like to randomly divide each address into one of two equal groups. My df looks roughly like this:

```
neighborhood <- c("armatage", "armatage", "armatage", "windom", "windom", "windom", "windom")
address <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
df <- data.frame(address, neighborhood)
```

but with many more neighborhoods with varying numbers of addresses. Using the randomizr package, so far I have been able to come up with this script, which iterates through each neighborhood name and comes up with a randomized list of 0s and 1s with the length of the number of rows within each neighborhood. The problem seems to be the second for loop, and actually assigning the randomized value to each row

```
for (i in df$neighborhood)
  n <- nrow(df[df$neighborhood == i, ])
  z <- complete_ra((n))
  for (row in 1:nrow(df[df$neighborhood == i, ]))
    df$group[row] <- z[row]
```

where `df$group` is where I would like to store the randomly assigned value. I would greatly appreciate any advice anyone might have. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way and avoids a double loop:

```r
library(data.table)

dt = as.data.table(df)
dt[, .(grp = sample(.N) %% 2, 
       address)
   , by = neighborhood]
#>    neighborhood grp address
#> 1:     armatage   1       a
#> 2:     armatage   0       b
#> 3:     armatage   1       c
#> 4:       windom   0       d
#> 5:       windom   1       e
#> 6:       windom   1       f
#> 7:       windom   0       g
```

Basically, if we take the *modulo* while also doing the sequence of the total number of addresses in each neighborhood, we can assign randomness.

### Background

Let's take a look at what the modulo operator `%%` does to the number sequence 1 to 4:

```
seq(from = 1, to = 4) ## or 1:4 or seq(4)
## [1] 1 2 3 4

seq(from = 1, to = 4) %% 2
## [1] 1 0 1 0
```

Mathematically, it tells us the remainder. That is, `1 / 2` has a remainder of 1; `2 / 2` has a remainder of 0; and so on. We can use this to make groupings. The problem is that this isn't random. That's where `sample()` comes in play

```r
sample(4) ## or sample(1:4) or sample(seq(1, 4))
## [1] 2 1 4 3
```

So if we combine *modulo* with `sample()`, we can effectively randomize these by groups if we know how many are in each group. That's where grouping such as [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) `dt[i, j, by]` syntax could help or [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) `tibble %>% group_by() %>% mutate()` syntax are of use. Yes, we could subset the unique neighborhoods in a loop, but it is more efficient to do groupings.

Since [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) is what helped me initially, let's take a look at that version:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(neighborhood) %>%
  mutate(group = sample(n()) %% 2)

## # A tibble: 7 x 3
## # Groups:   neighborhood [2]
##   address neighborhood group
##   <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>
## 1 a       armatage         1
## 2 b       armatage         0
## 3 c       armatage         1
## 4 d       windom           1
## 5 e       windom           0
## 6 f       windom           1
## 7 g       windom           0
```

Comment: +1 code works. Also, given the OP's experience, could benefit from more explanation, there's definitely some cleverness here.

Comment: Fair enough @Chris. It's hard to know capabilities of new posters - a lot of times its unclear the desired output format so I expect some back and forth. Related, new posters are also notorious for posting and then not following up with selecting answers or engaging - many probably solve it on their own. Regardless, I have made edits.

Comment: Hi @Cole. Thanks for the answer and added explanation, both are much appreciated. Though I don't have a lot of experience with R and coding in general, I do appreciate the cleverness that Chris pointed out! Just so I understand, does `sample(4)` randomly sample 4 numbers between 1 and 4, or does it create a random order to the sequence 1:4. Thanks again!

Comment: See `?sample`. By default, `if x has length 1, is numeric and [greater than or equal to] 1, sampling via sample takes place from 1:x.`. I think your question is the same thing stated two different ways. `sample(4)` is equivalent to `sample(1:4)`.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `dplyr`, `purrr`

```
neighborhood <- c("armatage", "armatage", "armatage", "windom", "windom", "windom", "windom")
address <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
df <- data.frame(address, neighborhood)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  # split original data into group of neighborhod by group_split from dplyr
  group_split(neighborhood) %>%
  # then for group of neighborhood apply function to split them into 2 group
  # based on their row number and number of group is 2
  map(.f = function(x) {
     x %>% group_by((row_number() - 1) %/% (n() / 2)) %>%
        nest %>% pull(.)
    })
```

Result of above code

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  address neighborhood
  <chr>   <chr>       
1 a       armatage    
2 b       armatage    

[[1]][[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  address neighborhood
  <chr>   <chr>       
1 c       armatage    


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  address neighborhood
  <chr>   <chr>       
1 d       windom      
2 e       windom      

[[2]][[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  address neighborhood
  <chr>   <chr>       
1 f       windom      
2 g       windom
```

In case you just want to add an index column to categorize each row into separate group.

```
df %>%
  group_by(neighborhood) %>%
  # cur_group_id gave group index + some math to calculate proper index
  # for each group base on their row number.
  mutate(group = (cur_group_id() - 1) * 2 + (row_number() - 1) %/% (n() / 2) + 1)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   neighborhood [2]
  address neighborhood group
  <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>
1 a       armatage         1
2 b       armatage         1
3 c       armatage         2
4 d       windom           3
5 e       windom           3
6 f       windom           4
7 g       windom           4
```